# From where I'm getting programs in Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

When I press Ubuntu button (former Windows button) on my keyboard and start typing application name I want to launch, I see there 2 instances of the same programm (in my case it's PyCharm IDE). I have checked my /usr/share/applications (it's having only the one PyCharm.desktop) and ~/Desktop folders (doesn't have anything).

I suspect I created somehow somewhere the .desktop shortcut for older version of PyCharm, which I'm not using anymore. The problem is I don't remember where and how I did it. And Ubuntu launcher isn't telling me from where program shortcut came from to my search results. So I can't get rid of this second instance of PyCharm shortcut.

**Could someone please send me to the webpage which explains ALL places Unity Launcher uses to find applications?** Any other help would be appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Thanks.

Comment: Check `.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: you are missing a `~/` there (`~/.local/share/applications/`) @jokerdino ;)

Comment: Yeah, you're right - forgot about .local somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow method: Search the entire filesystem for files named `*harm.*esktop` (PyCharm may be capitalized differently; desktop case may vary):

```
ls -R / | awk '
/:$/&&f{s=$0;f=0}
/:$/&&!f{sub(/:$/,"");s=$0;f=1;next}
NF&&f{ print s"/"$0 }' | grep "*harm.*esktop"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ha, yes this helped! Somehow I haven't thought about such a brute force solution. But I'm fine with it as long as it works. And commentors were right: I forgot to check "~/.local/share/applications/". Thanks!

Comment: @vladimir Always happy helpin bro.

Comment: @vladimir btw, I have absolutely no idea how the `awk` string that gets the full path works, i just chained `ls -r` into it and wrote up a simple regular expression for `grep` :)